# How hide hint, who change this part of code in sublimetext 3 for javascript files

Tags: sublimetext3

When I open js file in sublime text 3 and place cursor in any string of the code I see following:

Below is added one line without the line number, and in this line indented who and when made changes to this part. The color of the line is gray, like the comment. This information is taken from git. If I move the cursor to another line of code, then in the old place this line disappears and appears in a new place. This happens on the js files. With vue files, everything is fine. How can I disable this?

PS: When I take a screenshot this gray line disappears, so I can not show it in the picture

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I changed settings for gitgutter from

```
 "show_line_annotation": "auto"
```

to

```
 "show_line_annotation": "false"
```

Now all right